# How can I make this integration with Facebook for comments in the botton of my web page?

Tags: comments, facebook-like, facebook-integration

[image: Facebook integration for comments]

How is this done? Maybe with PHP or JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use this Facebook plugin: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/